# Firefox blurry/smoothing font issue

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts, blurry

Every other issue I could find about this is on macOS, but I'm on Windows, and I feel like it's a different problem

Here's the situation - I have a monospace font on my website, and some words will appear blurry on firefox while some words are pixel-perfect and beautiful.

```
<button id="run-training-program">TEST PROGRAM &gt;&gt;</button>
```

On Firefox:

[image]

(On Edge/Chromium, it's all blurry... but at least it's consistent)

[image]

If I resize the browser window, the layout of the page changes slightly and other words become blurry [image]

**How can I ensure the text is pixel aligned all the time throughout the page to prevent this blurriness to occur randomly?**

I added this to my CSS but to no avail (i'm not on OSX, so I guess it doesn't do anything)

```
font-smooth: inherit;
-webkit-font-smoothing: none !important;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: unset;
```

Comment: On body tag add this line
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;